# Убрать помехи при вставке картинки на страницу

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подгружаю баннеры на страницу таким вот образом:

```
$(".box").before("<img src=\"/banners/" + imgpath + "\" alt=\"\">");
```

но каждый раз при загрузке страницы на секунду появляются помехи и исчезают (стрелки на скриншоте указывают на них). Лучше всех это демонстрируют браузеры на основе Chromium.

Может картинки требуется подгружать в определенном месте или определенное время или по событию, в общем как избавиться от них? (сейчас подгрузка идет в середине html-кода)

Еще если убрать обратный слеш \, получаю ошибку `SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`, поэтому код экранирую, так как одинарные кавычки не могу использовать, здесь причина ошибки в кавычках?

[image: скрин]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Чтобы радовать глаз, эффект смены изображений (и родственные ему эффекты) 
>   должен иметь минимальное время отклика. Это означает, что необходим некоторый способ, гарантирующий предварительную загрузку всех необходимых изображений в кэш броузера. Для этой цели в клиентском JavaScript имеется специальный прикладной интерфейс: чтобы принудительно поместить изображение в кэш, нужно сначала создать объект `Image` с помощью конструктора `Image()`. Затем, записав в свойство `src` требуемый URL-адрес, загрузить изображение. Это изображение не будет добавлено в документ, поэтому, хотя изображение будет невидимо, броузер загрузит его и поместит в свой кэш. Позднее, когда тот же URL-адрес будет использоваться для изменения изображения, находящегося на экране, изображение быстро загрузится из кэша броузера.
>
> © Дэвид Флэнаган. "JavaScript. Подробное руководство"

Чтобы поместить изображение в кэш браузера приводится такой способ:

```
<script>(new Image()).src = "images/imageURL.gif";</script>
```

Так надо сделать для каждого пути к картинке `images/imageURL.gif`, которые вы будете использовать. Также от себя добавлю, что вы можете завести массив элементов `Image` и вставлять их, а не разметку.

Comment: Т.е требуется создать массив и загрузить абсолютно все картинки в кэш при первом посещении сайта пользователем?
Пожалуйста, приведите пример "вы можете завести массив элементов Image" в вашем ответе.

Comment: @Plush не обязательно все - это зависит от того, что вам нужно. Например, если вы динамически подгружаете их при прокрутке страницы - то загружайте на одну партию вперед. Когда надо будет показать - быстро показываете, но при этом грузите следующую партию. Если вы просто их загружаете динамически "дорисовывая страницу", то можно просто их вставлять через некоторый промежуток времени, после создания объекта Image() - но это увеличит время загрузки.